# Django Celery and Celery Beat Daemon Documentation

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I am working on deploying a django app with celery/celery beat to production. I can run everything just fine with celery running as a daemon with systemctl after following the documentation: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html#example-django-configuration. But the documentation is a bit confusing...do celery and celery beat need to be setup as a service with systemctl if you are using django? Or is the documentation showing that you need to configure both the service and django as it shows?

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy all three services(`django`, `celery worker`, `celery beat`) separately using supervisorctl. celery beat is like linux cron but with more fine grained control. It should be run in a separate process for scheduling tasks in the queue, which are then picked by the celery worker. Django provides web APIs and integrates tightly with celery to ease configuration and management.